# One of the timestamp fields change is not making the object dirty in gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm, dirty-checking

I have a domain class `Project`

```
package priz.api.project

import groovy.transform.AutoClone
import net.kaleidos.hibernate.usertype.JsonbMapType
import priz.api.challenge.Challenge
import priz.api.model.AuditableEntity
import priz.api.security.User
import priz.api.workspace.Workspace
import net.kaleidos.hibernate.usertype.ArrayType

@AutoClone
class Project extends AuditableEntity {

    String title
    String description
    String solution
    String currentSituation
    String disadvantages
    String problemStatement
    String successCriteria
    User owner

    User reviewer

    Challenge challenge

    Topic topic

    ProjectCertificationStatus certificationStatus = ProjectCertificationStatus.None

    Workspace workspace

    ProjectStatus status

    Map metaData

    Date followupSentAt
    Date lastWorkedOnAt

    Date lastChangedAt
    Date publishedAt
    Long secondsUnpublishedChanges

    Boolean open = false

    String publicTitle
    String publicDescription
    String[] keywords
    Map publicScopes
    String posterUrl
    String posterKey

    Date deletedAt
    User deletedBy

    static transients = ['posterUrl']

    static mapping = {
        table 'project'

        title type: 'text'
        description type: 'text'
        solution type: 'text'
        currentSituation column: 'current_situation', type: 'text'
        disadvantages type: 'text'
        problemStatement type: 'text'
        successCriteria column: 'success_criteria', type: 'text'

        certificationStatus column: 'certification_status', enumType: 'string'

        status column: 'status', enumType: 'string'

        metaData type: JsonbMapType

        followupSentAt column: 'followup_sent_at'
        lastWorkedOnAt column: 'last_worked_on_at'

        publicTitle column: 'public_title', type: 'text'
        publicDescription column: 'public_description', type: 'text'
        keywords column: 'keywords', type: ArrayType, params: [type: String]
        publicScopes column: 'public_scopes', type: JsonbMapType
        posterKey column: 'poster_key', type: 'text'

        lastChangedAt column: 'last_changed_at'
        publishedAt column: 'published_at'

        secondsUnpublishedChanges formula: 'EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (last_changed_at - published_at))'

        autoTimestamp true
    }

    static constraints = {
        title nullable: false, blank: false, size: 3..5000
        description nullable: true
        solution nullable: true
        currentSituation nullable: true
        disadvantages nullable: true
        problemStatement nullable: true
        successCriteria nullable: true

        owner nullable: false
        reviewer nullable: true
        challenge nullable: true
        topic nullable: true

        certificationStatus nullable: false
        status nullable: false

        createdBy nullable: false

        workspace nullable: false

        metaData nullable: true

        followupSentAt nullable: true
        lastWorkedOnAt nullable: true

        lastChangedAt nullable: true
        publishedAt nullable: true

        open nullable: false

        publicTitle nullable: true, black: true
        publicDescription nullable: true, black: true
        keywords nullable: true, black: true
        publicScopes nullable: true, black: true
        posterKey nullable: true, black: true
    }

}
```

The field `lastChangedAt` suppose to holed the last time when there was anything changed in the project. So, we are using Publisher/Subscrip to fire the events and listen to them to make this update. Eventually, the listener is calling this function:

```
Project updateLastChangedAt(Project project) {
        project.lastChangedAt = new Date()
        project.save()
    }
```

simple...

The problem is that the `lastChangedAt` field is not getting updated in DB. Debugging this, I saw that even though the field value is changing, the `project` object is still considered not dirty.

[image]

Why could that be? For all the other field changes, everything works as expected.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, I am getting the following error:

```
cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
```

It's the first time I see this one :(
Both of these methods are Transactional, so I can't even think about why would it be a read-only transaction.

```
Optional<Project> updateLastChangedAt(Long projectId) {
        projectRepositoryService.dangerousGet(projectId).map { updateLastChangedAt(it) }
    }
    
    Project updateLastChangedAt(Project project) {
        project.lastChangedAt = new Date()
        project.save(flush: true)
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question you asked, but does the built in auto timestamping capability we provide help?  I think you can rename `lastChangedAt` to `lastUpdated` and removed your code that is initializing the value, GORM can handle a lot of that for you.  https://gorm.grails.org/7.2.2/hibernate/manual/index.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

Comment: Automatic auditing is only built to track the changes of the object itself. In our case, we need to track anything that changed in the entire project, hence custom implementation

Comment: Roger that.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue... Not sure how I missed it.
My listener service had Transactional set to read-only set to true

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ProjectLastChangedListenerService {
...
```